# Android: Where to invoke rest call

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm making an Android application that is making REST calls with Retrofit2. But I am unsure about the structure of the appliation.

### Current scenario

When activity A is started (by an Intent from his parent) a REST call is made in the getData() method which will be invoked from the onCreate() method of the activity. To do this REST call, a variable (gateId) is passed with the intent that started activity A.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gate_action);
    loadingSpinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingSpinner);
    gateId = getIntent().getIntExtra(KeyConstants.GATE_ID, -1);

    getData(); // Make rest call and fill components on screen
}
```

From this activity (A) an other activity (B) is started with the startActivity() method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShipmentToggle.class);
intent.putExtra(KeyConstants.GATE_ID, gateActionDTO.getGateOid());
startActivity(intent);
```

### Questions

1. What is the best place to make the REST call? I don't think the onCreate() method is the best place to do this. I have to keep in mind that the REST call have to be made every time when coming back from activity B. This to always get the latest data from the API.
2. When the back button is pushed from activity B, the data (gateId) to make the REST call in activity A is lost. What is the best way to save this? (SharedPreferences, startActivityForResult, ...)

Comment: In a MVC or MVP approach, you would make a separate class to do the REST call and pass in a callback interface to the method that does the REST call

Comment: Depending on what your use case is re: "Best way to save this".  You can store data from the REST api response using SharedPreferences (do this for small non-trivial content) or use the Sqlite library that comes bundled with user phone (for more elaborate content).

Comment: The only thing that has to be saved is the gateId because I want to make the call every time again to get the latest data. At the moment I pass this variable in an intent to activity A. This won't be necessary then I guess as I can set the variable in the SharedPreferences in the parent activity of activity A and just read it in activity A?

Answer (score 0):

There is no best place inside your flow that could be considered best every time. You have to specify when exactly you need your call to be made. If you have to make that call once, on application start, you can place it inside `onCreate()` within SplashScreen activity and after that just switch to main activity.

Normally, you would instantiate a Presenter if you use MVP pattern and you will call `myPresenter.makeCallToApi();` on that object. It should be in `onCreate()` if there is no good reason to place it elsewhere. If you go back from activity B to caller activity, you can just check if you made your call and if so, don't do it again.

Provide more information on your specific use case.

**Update 1**

If in activity A you need data from API and then you go to B without caching that data (DB, file, SharedPreferences) then you should do that call again. You want your users to see same information when they go back. It it's updated, even better.

Comment: The call to the API in activity A should be made every time that the activity is loaded. So the onResume() method may look like a better place to invoke the call. Is that correct?

Checking if the call is already been made is not necessary, it should be made anyway. But the problem is that the gateId (parameter for REST call) is lost in activity A when coming back from activity B, because activity A is looking for this data in the intent.

Comment: I would use `onStart()` method because onResume may be triggered even if your activity wasn't stopped. If it's partially hidden (probably pressing Recents button will do that). So, you can end up with more than 1 call at the same time. Does your gateId change or is it constant? You could save it into Application class if it's constant value or just embed it into the call.

Comment: It is not a constant. It's coming from the parent activity of activity A. This is a listview with different gates. Depending on the gate you click on, the corresponding gateId will be passed to activity A.

Comment: If you are sure that you will go back to that activity at some point, you might want to take a look on `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods. You can also just pass back and forth additional data within intent, between activities. It's not very clean way of doing it but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the best way to save this? (SharedPreferences, startActivityForResult)**
you can go with `startActivityForResult if you want to pass the gateId from Activity B to A

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra("gateId", gateId);
        startActivityForResult(intent, addComment);
```

from the activity B you get the "gateID" after use finish the activtyB you can pass it back using

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //set ok result before finish the activity

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("gateId", gateId);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

        //write this to the last so returnIntent can pass the extra value ot onActivityResult or remove it.
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

and get the value of the "gateId" from `onActivityResult`. But since you put your restAPI call in onCreate, you need to call your RestAPI or `getData()` in `onActivityResult`. Using this workaroung will make you write more code in your activity.

**What is the best place to make the REST call? in your case**
The simplest way I think you can go with `SharedPreference` to save your "gateID" and put your `getData()`/api  in `onResume` and checking the gateID before you call the api. so You don't have to worry about the "gateID" value in ActivityB.

Answer (score 0):

What I started to do a while ago is to use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) to monitor requests and it works beautifully without sending params and callbacks all around.

So basically I have a singleton where I can initiate requests, which are then wrapped by Observables which are then monitored by whomever needs it.

So Fragment A sends data whenever it needs to do an action, refresh, whatever. It does not care if anyone will get it.

Fragment B Monitors ObservableB which should have requests with tag [B]. It does not need to know from where the request comes from it just knows its for it. So Fragment B will receive the request in the case when:

1) it has been initialized before the request was received

2) it has been initialized after the request was received

if Fragment B dies before the request is send it just unsubscribes from the Observable.

This way the code is clean modular and super easy to test and debug and faster(reactive) of course :)

Retrofit has the ability to return Observables and it added the cancellation option in version 2 which is handy.

I personally use extension of Volley i call [jus](https://github.com/apptik/jus). It has almost the same capabilities of Retrofit also.

What is nice with it is that you can wrap the whole request queue in a single observable and monitor all requests form one place.